# Segoe UI Symbol or vector graphics for WPF icons?

Tags: wpf, icons, vector-graphics

We are building a WPF application and would like dynamic icons (scale without loss and custom colors).

I've come across sites like http://modernuiicons.com/ and http://www.thexamlproject.com/ that provide nice vector paths.

On the other hand, there's the Segoe UI Symbol font used by Windows Metro apps. Because it's a font, it is also vector based and the size can be set by font size.

Using a font seems the cleanest and fastest way.
Are there any technical limitations using a font for icons (can a new symbol be added to the font)?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: +1 for some nice links, but I'm afraid that your question is primarily opinion based and so is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this website and quite likely to be closed by the community.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm actually interested in the technical issues with both methods. I wouldn't want to get stuck using the Segoe UI Symbol font. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done more research on the subject and decided to go with the Segoe UI Symbol font since our target audience works exclusively on Windows 8.

Segoe UI Symbol Pros:

- Installed on Windows 7 & 8
- +1000 icons
- Windows 8 metro familiarity
- Easy to use

Segoe UI Symbol Cons:

- More difficult to create a new icon (described [here](http://learnwpf.com/post/2012/03/19/Flexible-Metro-style-icons-in-WPF-with-Embedded-Fonts.aspx))
- No license available for non-Windows systems

Sources:

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/03/windows-8-1000-metro-icons-you-already.html
http://learnwpf.com/post/2012/03/19/Flexible-Metro-style-icons-in-WPF-with-Embedded-Fonts.aspx
http://www.beabigrockstar.com/blog/3-ways-to-add-modern-icon-goodness-windows-8-1
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/segoe-ui-font-licensing

Comment: Thank you for the links. Segoe UI symbols are the recommended way for Windows Store and Phone apps to create icons, so it makes sense to use them for WPF apps that will probably be run in Windows 8.